# How to reset TextRange for select only last selection in RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, selection, richtextbox, textcolor, textrange

I'm working in wpf and visual basic. When I select text in RichTextBox i use TextRange:

```
dim selection1 as New TextRange(Richtextbox.selection.start,Richtextbox.selection.end)
```

Later:

```
selection1.ApplyPropertyValue(ForegroundProperty, brushes.Red)
```

When I am marking text many times the color changes also in the previous selections. I want change color only last selection. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you cache the previous selection and previous color?

```
RichTextBox.BeginChange();
selection?.ApplyPropertyValue(ForegroundProperty, lastColor);
selection = RichTextBox.Selection;
selection.ApplyPropretyValue(ForegroundProperty, newColor);
RichTextBox.EndChange();
```